# Fine Uploader - Submit by Form instead of AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have got on page Instance of Fine Uploader. My file is uploaded to a server by AJAX, but I want to have got similar behavior to normal HTML Input File, and Input Submit because I want to have got access to $_FILES in new response.

Is this possible?

Comment: slightly difficult to understand!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the location of the file after the AJAX upload, why not use `file_get_contents` function to retrieve the file in your response?

Unless you can tell us why you need to specifically use the $_FILES global?

Of course you will have to get the file name from your AJAX upload, but that can be returned and used in the AJAX response.